# How to take data from multiple json files for validation through Cucumber?

Tags: java, json, selenium, cucumber, gson

Currently, I have a set of json files in the automation framework. In each json file there is an array containing a set of similar json objects. I need to use these files for validations from web application using cucumber and selenium in java. Below is the example of the json array present in each json file:

```
[
  {
    "Status": "Active",
    "Company": "XYZ",
    "PackageId": "551819",
    "ProductCode": "BACC"

  },
  {
    "Status": "Active",
    "Company": "ABC",
    "PackageId": "551829",
    "ProductCode": "IRE7"

  },
  {
    "Status": "Active",
    "Company": "MAU",
    "PackageId": "551009",
    "ProductCode": "BACC"

  },
  {
    "Status": "Active",
    "Company": "XYZ",
    "PackageId": "551073",
    "ProductCode": "AXM"

  }
]
```

All the files contains similar json array. My framework needs to take all these files and take the data from each json object of each array of each file and validate it with the data reflecting in web application using a single scenario of a Step definition file of Cucumber. Can anyone please suggest me how can it be done as i have never run a set of files for data provider in Cucumber framework?

Answer (score 0):

is this can help you ?

Data Driven Testing using JSON with Cucumber

We have to do lot of amendments in our project in this chapter to implement Data Driven Technique using JSON files:

```
1.Decide what data needs to pass through JSON files
2.Create JSON Data set
3.Write a Java POJO class to represent JSON data
4.Pass JSON data file location to Properties file and Write a method to read the same
5.Create a JSON Data Reader class
6.Modify FileReaderManager to accommodate JSON Data Reader
7.Modify Checkout Steps file to pass Test Data to Checkout Page Objects 
8.Modify Checkout Page object to use Test Data object

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/data-driven-testing-using-json-with-cucumber/
```

Comment: Yeah. But the problem here is I have a set of similar files unlike a single file as given in the referred site.